# jquery validate remote response format

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Trying to validate nickname using the remote method

```
rules: {
     nickname: {
           required: true,
           remote: "checknick.php"
     }
}
```

And checknick is here

```
$name = addslashes($_POST['nickname']);

$sql="select * from names where nickname='$name'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num_rows > 0 ) {
   $valid='false';
} else {
   $valid = 'true';
}


echo $valid;
```

This isn't validating for me. Can anybody help me out here.

Comment: you're much more likely to get help if you go back to the other questions you've asked and choose an answer for each as accepted. Just click on the checkbox outline to the left of the answer you like best.

Answer (score 1):

Which validation plugin are you using?

I would try json encoding the response:

```
echo json_encode($valid);
```

Comment: The jquery-validate plugin (docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation)

Answer (score 0):

json_encode($valid); isnt the issue, remote uses $_GET['nickname']